# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/

Tags: java, android

Building basic app and getting IllegalArgumentException: Had a Button to launch camera app where I am trying to save image to pictures. `dispatchTakePictureIntent();` method is called when I click Image button

Found few similar issues but that couldn't resolve my issue:

- [Android: FileProvider IllegalArgumentException Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/**/files/Videos/final.mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345275/android-fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-th)
- [FileProvider "Failed to find configured root" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293114/fileprovider-failed-to-find-configured-root-exception)

Below is my code. Can some one help what I am missing?

```
public class CatalogDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    public String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/CatalogData";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //verifyStoragePermissions();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog_data);
        final Button btCamera=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
        final Button btSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

        final EditText etProductName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_productName);
        final EditText etProductDescription=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_description);
        final TextView finalText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_saved_text);
        File dir=new File(path);
        if(!dir.isDirectory()){
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        btCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               /* Intent takePictureIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }*/
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
        btSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newProductDataStr=etProductName.getText()+","+etProductDescription.getText()+"|";
                File file=new File(path+"/catalogdata.txt");
                System.out.println("Path:"+path);
                writeToFile(newProductDataStr,getApplicationContext());
                String data=readFromFile(getApplicationContext());
                finalText.setText(data);
                //finalText.
                String []splitData=data.split("|");

                //System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>////"+splitData.length+"/////>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+splitData[splitData.length-4]);
            }
        });

    }

    private void writeToFile(String data,Context context) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("config1.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception"+ "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private String readFromFile(Context context) {

        String ret = "";

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("config1.txt");

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }

        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            String ImagePath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    bitMap,
                    "demo_image",
                    "demo_image"
            );
            System.out.println("Saved Image in :"+ImagePath);
        }
    }

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if(!storageDir.isDirectory()){
            storageDir.mkdir();
        }
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                try {
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                            photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //galleryAddPic();
        }
    }
    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

}
```

> manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".CatalogDataActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</manifest>
```

> file_paths.xml placed at res/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

> activity_catalog_data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_catalog_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate.CatalogDataActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:text="Open Camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:elevation="0dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Product Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_camera"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/et_productName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_description"
        android:text="Enter Description"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_productName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_image1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_description" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_image1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:id="@+id/iv_image2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_image3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_image2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image2" />

    <Button
        android:text="Save Product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_image2"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/tv_saved_text" />

</RelativeLayout>

> W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170222_233359_1077283085.jpg
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
W/System.err:     at com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate.CatalogDataActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(CatalogDataActivity.java:176)
W/System.err:     at com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate.CatalogDataActivity.access$000(CatalogDataActivity.java:33)
W/System.err:     at com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate.CatalogDataActivity$1.onClick(CatalogDataActivity.java:61)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 2537 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=101KB, data=124KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=64KB, data=67KB
```

Comment: Use 6.0 taget sdk ?

Comment: Minimum sdk 4 and I have tested it in 7.0

Comment: You need give runtime permission which i give below answer

Answer (score 17):

I think these is the right way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />
  <external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
  <cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="." />
  <external-cache-path
    name="external_cache"
    path="." />
<files-path
    name="files"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: yeah this worked. As I was saving file using context.getFilesDir(). Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can not access the `com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate / files / Pictures directory in the root directory / storage / emulated / 0 /(external-path)` directly .You need to specify its full path, that is,' `Android / data / com.androidapp.natty .catalogcreate / files / Pictures`'.

You can also use external-files-path (corresponding to `/storage/emulated/0/com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate/files/` directory), and then specify its Pictures directory.
code shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.androidapp.natty.catalogcreate/files/Pictures" />
    </paths>
```

or:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-files-path name="my_images" path="" />
    </paths>
```

or:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    </paths>
```

Comment: Some words of explanation usually are appreciated on stack overflow.

Comment: I'm not good at English, and it's the first time I've made a comment on stack overflow. I hope you understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Second one also worked for me... this was a huge headache before, thanks!

Comment: I'm having similar issue. Could you please help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67279734/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-that-contains

Answer (score 3):

use file provider in manifest

and declare provider_path as mentioned below

```
    <external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
```

It will fix the problem

Comment: Does this mean we are asking for an access to the whole root folder instead of app specific folder?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by moving

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

code to application level in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this if your are a beginner or little confusion about fileprovider configure

- `<files-path/> - internal app storage, Context#getFilesDir()`
- `<cache-path/> - internal app cache storage, Context#getCacheDir()`
- `<external-path/> - public external storage, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`
- `<external-files-path/> - external app storage, Context#getExternalFilesDir(null)`
- `<external-cache-path/> - external app cache storage, Context#getExternalCacheDir()`

**Here is a case solution genuine or secure**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="/" />
</paths>
```

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns path like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

so

```
<external-path name="my_images" path="/" />
```

enough to access all file inside folder if you want some control on the folder you can change like this `<external-path name="my_images" path="/b" />` .then you get only **b** folder, file and folder

Comment: what About Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory ?

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
private static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private Uri fileUri;
int isCamera = 1;



    if (options[item].equals("Camera")) {
        isCamera = 1;
        if (checkandRequestPermission()) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
               fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(EditProfile.this, getPackageName()+ ".provider", getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE));
               intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
           } else {
                      fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                      intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
             }
             startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
          }
       } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                isCamera = 0;
                if (checkandRequestPermission()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
       } 
}


private boolean checkandRequestPermission() {
        int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int storageread = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int storagewrite = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        List<String> listpermissionNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (camera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listpermissionNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (storageread != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listpermissionNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (storagewrite != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listpermissionNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (!listpermissionNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EditProfile.this, listpermissionNeeded.toArray(new String[listpermissionNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and also add onRequestPermission result.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    //  task you need to do.
                    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                        if (isCamera == 1) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(EditProfile.this, getPackageName()+ ".provider", getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE));
                                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                            } else {
                                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                            }
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having similar issue. Could you look into it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67279734/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-that-contains

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getGROUPSTORAGEPremission(){
        int hasWriteContactsPermission = Splash_activity.this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE);
        if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Splash_activity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{  Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE},
                    PERMISSION_GROUPSTORAGE);
        } else {

            //your code here
        }

    }


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_RECEIVESMS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GROUPSTORAGE) {
                //your code here
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
//              Toast.makeText(mContext, "STORAGE Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                      .show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked authorities in provider

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.tomodori.crew"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```