# FileProvider accessing Room database throws an IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-room, android-fileprovider

I want to backup Room database of my app. I'm trying to get uri of database using `FileProvider`, but it throws IAE at this line:

```
 Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.trulden.friends.FileProvider", getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME));
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` I have this provider tag:

```
<application .. >
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                />
        </provider>
...
</application>
```

`provider_paths.xml` looks like this:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="database" path="databases/"/>
</paths>
```

The error:

```
08-29 13:28:27.430 8146-8146/com.trulden.friends E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Failed to find configured root that contains 
/data/data/com.trulden.friends/databases/friends_database
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
```

Result of `getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath()` looks like this:

```
/data/data/com.trulden.friends/databases/friends_database
```

Comment: possible duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407486/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-that-contains

Comment: isn't doc pretty straight ? *`<files-path name="name" path="path" />` - Represents files in the `files/` subdirectory of your app's internal storage area.*

Comment: @Selvin yeah, you are right. Because of `databases/` in the error log I thought, that the FileProvider actually tries to read file from there, not from `files/` subdirectory. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileProvider` can access files only in `files/` subdirectory, so I copied them there.

Still can't understand, why the error looks like `Failed to find`, when it should be something like `Failed to access`.

Also, Room database actually have three files. I got their paths like that:

```
String dbPath = getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
String[] dbFiles = {dbPath, dbPath + "-wal", dbPath + "-shm"};
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileProvider` does not support serving content from that location. If you wish to serve directly from that location, you would need to implement your own `ContentProvider`.

Also, note that a database may be multiple files, particularly if WAL is enabled. `getDatabasePath()` is from API Level 1, back when WAL did not exist and a SQLite database was always just one file.